# SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERRORr while running package

Tags: ssis, oledb, flat-file

I created a package with SSIS to upload a csv file to 3 different tables
It works in a way that it reads a csv file and then separates its columns to 3 different tables whereas some columns get uploaded to all tables (ids and such)

When I run the package I get the following error:

```
TITLE: Package Validation Error
------------------------------

Package Validation Error

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Error at Upload unrestated domestic [Load data to table 1 [7346]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unspecified error".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The metadata could not be determined because every code path results in an error; see previous errors for some of these.".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid object name 'dbo.DomisticUnrestFundam1'.".

Error at Upload unrestated domestic [Load data to table 1 [7346]]: Failed to open a fastload rowset for "[dbo].[DomisticUnrestFundam1]". Check that the object exists in the database.

Error at Upload unrestated domestic [SSIS.Pipeline]: "Load data to table 1" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".

Error at Upload unrestated domestic [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.

Error at Upload unrestated domestic: There were errors during task validation.

 (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

It shows the error marks on the database upload part (OLE DB destination).

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Are you connecting to the right server?  Are you connecting to the right SQL instance on the server? Does the account running the SSIS package have the proper security access to the database on the server?  Do your tables exist?

Comment: Furthermore, is `dbo.DomisticUnrestFundam1` a table or a view?

Comment: Yes the server, instance and table were correct.
The problem seemed to be that I made a copy of my OLEDB elements and those copies didnt seem to work.

Now that I properly remade (dragged new element to the field) my OLEDB destination blocks, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is an issue with the oledb connection to the following object:
dbo.DomisticUnrestFundam1

The reason is that the link to the object is broken. I would leave the old oledb destination there, then add a new oledb destination in the same package, then go through and check that everything is OK for the new oledbdestination. Often adding a new one in will tell you why it can't connect. Then if you find you can add the new one in OK, once it all looks ok you can remove the old oledb connection and link the new one.

By adding the new destination in, you will start out with default properties and you can preview it to  make sure all the connections, permissions, mappings are OK.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I edited my package and remade all the OLEDB destinations. I used to make the old ones by making one then copying it to make others. Also, the first I made properly wasnt anymore used (I deleted it for some reason) so all the OLEDB destination elements were copies of one that was deleted. I didnt think this matters but I now properly remade (dragged a new element to the field) all my OLDDB Destination elements and it worked.
It seems then that you shouldn't copy elements in SSIS

Thanks again!